# Decryption of modified encoded string returning correct decrypted string

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I have a created a function to encrypt and decrypt a string

```
function encryptDecrypt($string, $action = 'e') {
        $password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
        $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
        $output=false;

// Must be exact 32 chars (256 bit)
        $password = substr(hash('sha256', $password, true), 0, 32);

// IV must be exact 16 chars (128 bit)
        $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);

        if ($action == 'e') {
            $output = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($string, $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
            $output = strtr(
                $output,
                array(
                '+' => '.',
                '=' => '-',
                '/' => '~'
                    )
            );
        } else if ($action == 'd') {
            $string = strtr(
            $string,
            array(
                '.' => '+',
                '-' => '=',
                '~' => '/'
                    )
            );
            $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

string `"sid=1"` provided to this function to encrypt returns `"~zhn21ZrTPEqI034H2.FGg--"` as encrypted string and it's decryption should return `"sid=1"`.
The issue I am facing is when I modified the encoded string from `"~zhn21ZrTPEqI034H2.FGg--"` to `"~zhn21ZrTPEqI034H2.FGg"`, the decryption of the modified string still returns `"sid=1"` as decrypted string and this should not have happened.
Please HELP me what should I do to prevent this from happening.

Comment: -- is *base64 padding* which may be needed in the final base64 output. base64 decoding may succeed without the padding as it can be calculated at decode time by the base64 implementation. Its not an issue with regards to security (unlike your IV) as you are not modifying the ciphertext at all, you are just removing optional characters from its base64 representation.

Comment: @AlexK. a layman won't get it. As per to a layman it's a change in the string and it should give error.

Comment: If removing padding does not affect your decryption then base64_decode() clearly does not need them, so if $output ends in one or two `=` characters just remove them.

Comment: @AlexK. I have no idea whether it will affect or not as I haven't tested it with other strings

Comment: if decrypting `abc==` and `abc` both work then trailing `=` are optional and can therefore be discarded.

Comment: @AlexK. Okay. accepted. I tested it with other strings and it works but I don't think if that's a solution.